# Point Controller to View that is not in the same structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

How do you get a controller to recognize a view where the controller is in a root controllers folder but the view is in a folder 2 or 3 levels in in another folder?  Right now in my controller, it cannot find my view even though the View name is the same as the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you need to do is to create your own custom ViewEngine. [Here is an article on this](http://coderjournal.com/2009/05/creating-your-first-mvc-viewengine/)

Or, here is something that might even be [more of what you need?](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx)

OR, you might be able to do [this](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/asp-net-mvc-tip-24-retrieve-views-from-different-folders.aspx). From the article:

```
return View( @"~\Folder\View.aspx");
```

Comment: yea was hoping that wasn't the only option

Comment: I just updated my answer to a possibility. I have not tried it personally, but it is worth a shot.